# How to use URL field with formula editor to build a dynamic link

Tags: formula

I have created a URL field to be able to build dynamic links using a static part and I need to be able to add query parameters to the link using fields available on the object where I am creating that fields.
I have tried building the static part as a string and referencing the other fields I need as variables, but I am getting error messages:

```
"https://linkurl.com/somapage?e=" + $Label.emailId + "&s=" + $Label.lead
```

As you can see, I am trying to build the link by concatenating a base url of `https://linkurl.com/somapage` and adding two parameters, `e` and `s`which the values for, should be populated from two fields on the object where I am building this.

Error message:

> Error: Syntax error. Extra $Label.emailId

Am I building this link in the correct way?
How could I improve this to make it work?

Comment: Is this the complete formula? The formula mentioned above compiles without any issues. `"https://linkurl.com/somapage?e=" + $Label.emailId + "&s=" + $Label.lead`

Comment: yes, this is the complete formula

Comment: As a admin when I use this in a formula field, it compiles for me (provided that the label exists as part of my org namespace). Would you be able to add a screen shot for this. Are you using it in a formula field or somewhere else? JS action or workflow?

Comment: In formula field - how do I make sure that those labels exists? I don't usually work in core Salesforce so maybe I missed a step? I just want to be able to pull a couple of fields from the object that I am working with, eg. if it was Contact, let's say I wanted to reference Contact.Id and Contact.FirstName in the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the formula field is on Contact, then

```
"https://linkurl.com/somapage?e=" + Id + "&s=" + FirstName
```

Labels are typically used for constants.  For example, a standard copyright notice for use in a footer. Other uses for labels are for error messages that can be translated or easily changed without having to touch the rest of the system

Comment: Thank you, it worked!